# Passing an object to a Meteor method using swiftDDP

Tags: ios, swift, meteor

I am trying to use meteor and iOS for a project of mine. My problem is that I am trying to connect to a meteor function using the swiftDDP library. When sending data it is sent in the wrong format. How can I pass an object from iOS that Meteor (running in js) will accept? Is there a way to do this using a string? I have working javascript code that calls the same functions how would I pass the same form of data from iOS/swift?

Javascript

```
Meteor.call('xxx', {a: 1, b: 2, c: "some text"});
```

IOS (passes anyobject)

```
Meteor.call("xxx", ?? )
```

Comment: Solved this I created a object in this format on IOS swift 
        let data: [String : AnyObject] = [
            "time" : {time object}
            "foo" : "1",
            "blah" : "1",
        ]
Then simply called 
Meteor.call("events.add", params: [data]) { result, error in
                    // Do something with the method result
                    NSLog("call worked")
                }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this I created a object in this format on IOS swift let data: [String : AnyObject] = [ "time" : {time object} "foo" : "1", "blah" : "1", ] Then simply called Meteor.call("events.add", params: [data]) { result, error in // Do something with the method result NSLog("call worked") }